# Cannot access/control ongoing downloads after closing and reopening the Android app

Tags: java, android, download

My android java app has Offline Video feature like the YouTube app. I do not use `android.app.DownloadManager` because it does not support pausing the downloads(or as I know).

I have been using a third party download manager library(tonyodev.fetch2) and it does the work done but the problems are:

- How can I make the download independent of the app closing/opening etc and also being able to control it when required from an Activity.
- If I use a Service for the above problem, what do I use, `IntentService` or just normal `Service` keeping in mind I have to know about the ongoing downloads and control it(pause/stop/resume) from any activity.

I have been using android `worker` class which extents `ListenableWorker` but I cant seem to make things work as required.

I have been struggling with this for a long time now any help is welcome, or a totally new approach for this particular problem.

Comment: `IntentService` is deprecated starting with Android R. Foreground service is the only valid approach. To control your service simply bind to it from your activity.

Comment: What happens if the Activity is destroyed and I want to pause the download, will the variables retain values if this service is bound to another activity, or should I use Shared Preferences for this? Sorry I'm not familiar with Services.